# Looking for a way to set (default) zoom level of iWorks app

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite, keynote

Scanning the internet I found that in the past one could set the `view scale` or `fit width` of an iWorks application like this in Applescript:

```
tell window 1 of application "Keynote"
    set fit width to true
end tell
```

or

```
tell window 1 of application "Keynote"
    set view scale to 80
end tell
```

Both these methods don't work in Yosemite anymore (and most likely did not work since Snow Leopard according to some Google searches.
I also looked through the Applescript API Library for Keynote and could not see anything that refers to a `view scale` or zoom level.

Is there really no way anymore to set these via AppleScript?

My end goal is actually just to have new iWorks apps always be set to "Fit in Window", but lacking the possibility to set and save it via a Theme, I was assuming that AppleScript would be the only possible solution.

Comment: You can `get bounds of window 1` and set `width of the document` based on the computed result.

Comment: That's just the window size itself, but it would not change the zoom-style, hence if I decrease the window size, the content will not decrease with it.